# UPDATE and REVISE rest api is not working in vTiger CRM cloud service

Tags: api, rest, vtiger, vtigercrm, dynamic-picklist-vtiger

So basically I need to use the update/revise Rest API to update the fields in the vTiger CRM.

But when I am using the rest API (link : https://help.vtiger.com/article/147111249-Rest-API-Manual) to update the fields, I am getting the error as "400 Unsupported operations: The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax."
My api : `endpoint/reviseelement=convert_into_json_string({id:5x369, potentialname:'demo2'})`

Also apart from this, I had used the SQL query Rest API, to update the record in the modules, but it is also giving me the same error as: "400 Unsupported operations: The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax."
My Api query : `endpoint/query?query=UPDATE Potentials SET potentialname = 'demo2 where id = 5x369;`

Also by using the webservice(https://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/third-party-app-integration.html) rest api I am getting error like : "Permission to perform the operations is denied for id: ".

So how can I use the update api. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

For web services API (https://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/third-party-app-integration.html),

When you pass the payload data, make sure you're passing the x-www-form-urlencoded form of data.

Also, make sure you're passing 'element' argument with value like this:
{"id": "10x11471458", "leadsource": "Facebook"}.

if you're still facing this issue, you can share more details and I'll be happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need to do this the following should work.

Method: POST
End Point: /revise

Headers: "Authorization: Basic YOUR_TOKEN"

Body:
{
"element": {
"id":"5x369",
"potentialname": "demo2"
}
}

reference: https://www.vtiger.com/docs/rest-api-for-vtiger#/Revise